# Wrong understanding of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python, so I apologize if this question is naive.

I consider a list `elements = [3, 6, 7]`. I would like to write a series of instructions which transform the list `l = [[], [], []]` into `l = [[3], [6], [7]]`. If I write the (naive) code below :

```
pos = 0
for i in range(3):
    l[i].append(elements[i])
print(l)
```

then the output is not as I expected. Indeed, the list `l` becomes `l=[[3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 7]]`. My reasoning was the following one : when `i=0` only `l[0]` (the first element of `l`) should be modified. However, it is not the case. After the first run in the loop, the list `l` is : `l = [[3], [3], [3]]`. Where am I wrong ?

Of course, this could be easily solved using list comprehension:

```
l = [[elements[j]] for j in range(3)]
```

Comment: How did you actually create `l`?  Did you actually do it with the line `l = [[], [], []]`?  Include in your code snippet the line that creates `l`.

Comment: It looks like you tried `l = [[]]*3`.

Comment: Your code works for me in Python3 and Python2. Some of the code you show here (probably the definition of `l`) is not the real code you used for the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the part of the code you haven't posted (that's why you should post *complete examples* when you ask questions here).

What has happened is that `l` contains three references to the *same* list. When you append an element to that list and then print `l`, you still see three copies of that list.

You need to create `l` in a way that truly makes three separate lists:

```
l = [ [], [], [] ] #good
l = [ [] for x in range(3) ] #good
l = [ [] ] * 3  #bad
```

Answer (score 0):

### Three copies of the same list

It appears that you've constructed your list 'l' not from three empty lists, but of three references to *the same* single empty list. This means that any changes done to it through l[0] are reflected also if you look at the same list through l[1].